# Express route with param is inconsistent. Is it my code?

Tags: node.js, express

So I am working on a social networking project, I added the ability to upload images and an API route that can return image objects from a DB so that I can display them. This was all working fine, then I took a few days break from it (new game came out) and now the API rout isn't working, sort of.

So here is the route:

```
    router.get("/image/all/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Triggered: Images/all/ID");
  Image.find({owner_id: req.params.id}).populate("comments").exec(function(err, images) {
    if(err) {
      req.flash('error', err.toString());
      return next();
    } else {
      console.log("images API trigger");
      res.json(images);
      return next();
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({url: "/image/all/" + uid, success: function(data) {

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  let img = "<a class='aPic' href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.view-image-modal' data-id='" + data[i]._id + "'> <img src='" + data[i].thumb + "' class='thumbnail pull-left'></a>";
  $('#proBox').append(img);
  imageData.push(data[i]);
}

$('.view-image-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var id = button.data('id');
  var image;
  for(let i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
    console.log(imageData[i]._id + "  |  " + id);
    let imId = imageData[i]._id.toString();
    if(imId == id){
      image = imageData[i];
      console.log("Found: " + imageData[i].file);
    }
  }
  let splt = image.file.split(".");
  let ext = "." + splt[splt.length - 1];
  $('.modal-content img').attr('src', "/images/uploads/" + id + ext);
  $('.modal-title').html("Uploaded: " + moment(image.created).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
  $('#imgDesc').val(image.description);

  $('#imgEdit-button').attr('data-id', id);
  $('#imgDelete-button').attr('data-id', id);
  //Update comments section
});
```

}});

So I get this url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/image/all/5989da1afdc58624a0b10fda

the console gives error 404, if I put this in the address bar i get "Cannot GET ..." however if I add or remove a letter from the id, it returns an array as it is supposed to.

I also tried this in an incognito window to make sure it wasn't a cached file issue or anything like that. Any ideas?

Comment: Not 100% sure how req.flash works but when an error occurs you call next. i think if you do that and you do not have an error handler, then you will get a 404. In your error case, try return `res.json(err)` instead of `return next()` and you might actually see why it is failing. Maybe the _id is badly formed and mongoose is rejecting it - thats just a wild guess.

Comment: GENIUS!!! Thank you, I forgot I had it set that way. I forgot I added the populate("comments") and hadn't called the mongoose model for it.

Comment: if you submit that as answer I will mark it as correct, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, when an error occurs, you call `next()`. If you do that and you do not have an error handler, then you will get a 404. In your error case, return res.json(err) instead of return next() and you might actually see why it is failing.

Alternatively you can add an error handler as your final middleware and call next(err).